# Best way to store Non-Uniform 3D Data in HDF5?

Tags: c++, hdf5

I'm going to use the HDF5-format for measurement data. The data is 3D: Channels x Traverse Steps x Samples.

My current challenge (never call it problem): some traverse steps should be able to have more samples. Little Ascii-Picture as explanation:

```
    ______
   /_____/|       1 - Traverse Steps
1 /_____/_|__     2 - Channels
 /__________/|    3 - Samples
 |         | |
2|_________|/
       3
```

How to store this in HDF5 in a good way? My approaches so far:

1. Extendible Datasets (on chunks): There is a documentation (http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/Tutor/extend.html) but I am not able to adjust this for my problem. The whole data just get the size of the largest data.
2. one Matrix for every Traverse Step: Not nice when doing a calculation for one channel on each traverse step because it has to read each Matrix.

I would prefer option 1 but I'm not even sure if its possible? Does anyone has experience if option 2 would become a performance bottleneck?